# Microsoft C# command line compiler not finding .dll in external directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, csc

I would like to compile a C# program from the command line in a Linux terminal. My csc.exe is added to my Path and works correctly. The directory layout is as follows:

```
|-- Program.cs
|-- Otherfiles.cs
|-- bin
|    |-- Debug
|    |    |-- Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

From the top directory, I use the following command to compile:

```
csc *.cs /r:./bin/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
--> error CS2001: Source file 'r:bin/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json.dll' could not be found
```

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do here, or will I just have to copy the .dll files I want into the same directory as `Program.cs`, as is done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722832/csc-exe-reference-external-dll-file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`/reference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yabyz3h4.aspx) argument is only used to indicate the name of the assembly.

To specify additional directories to search for assembly files use the [`/lib`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5bac5fx.aspx) argument:

```
csc *.cs /r:Newtonsoft.Json.dll /lib:"./dir with spaces/need quotes", ./bin/Debug
```

> Use /lib to specify the directory in which one or more of your assembly references is located. The /lib topic also discusses the directories in which the compiler searches for assemblies.

Comment: Very helpful, the Microsoft page on command line builds doesn't event include /r.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0.aspx

Comment: Which I'm aware is a shortcut for some other command, it just isn't mentioned.