# how to use library in c#

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

this is my first c# trail, I created a dll file and I want to use its classes in another c# file, but when I do compiling I get this error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HelloLib' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>           assembly reference?)

HelloLib.dll:

```
namespace HelloLib{
    public class Hello{
        public string greeting(){
            return "Hello, World!";
        }
    }
}
```

MyMain.cs:

```
using HelloLib;

public class MyMain{
    public static void Main(){
        System.Console.WriteLine(Hello.greeting());
    }
}
```

I compiled the library using the CMD command:

```
csc /target:library /out:C:\PATH_TO_DESKTOP\Hello.dll C:\PATH_TO_DESKTOP\Hello.cs
```

Then I tried to compile "MyMain" file as exe with this command:

```
csc /target:exe /out:C:\PATH_TO_DESKTOP\MyMain.exeC:\PATH_TO_DESKTOP\MyMain.cs
```

Comment: after you fix this error you will get another error. make your `greeting` method static.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [csc.exe reference external .dll file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722832/csc-exe-reference-external-dll-file)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary if I don't want to make this method static, how I can create an instance of the class?

Comment: use Hello hello = new Hello();

Comment: Why are you not using Visual Studio? It has Community & Express editions which are free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass reference path of assembly while compiling exe project using /reference or /r option.

```
csc /target:exe /out:C:\PATH_TO_DESKTOP\MyMain.exe C:\PATH_TO_DESKTOP\MyMain.cs /r:C:\PATH_TO_DESKTOP\Hello.dll
```

With above command your exe should get compile however as someone has commented above that you are trying to call greeting() method with class name and since its not marked as static method your exe compilation will throw error. To fix it you need to either make greeting() method (in Hello.dll) as static or Create instance of Hello class using "new" operator and then call greeting() method on that instance. Once you make this change then your exe should get compiled without any error.