# Add a NuGet package to a non VS .cs file

Tags: c#, json, nuget

I have a small Json parser C# file that requires a nuget package. I have it as part of another major project (non VS), so I don't want to create a VS project in here. I tried something like this from the command line:

```
nuget install Newtonsoft.Json
```

This returns a success message, but all it does is download the package to my current project. When I try to use the package from my file I get this:

```
 The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How do I get my file to recognize the library? I'm kind of new to .cs, so if there is a better solution to this I'm all about it.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: What does your command line look like for compiling your program?

Comment: **csc jsonParser.cs**
I've also tried including the library, but it says "source file could not be opened" like this:
**csc jsonParser.cs  Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2**

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10722922/1141432).

Comment: -lib or any of the other options seemed to worked. I keep getting "Newtonsoft" could not be found